# Почему не работает transition(анимация) в обратную сторону?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При открытие выпадающего меню transition работает, но при закрытие transition перестает работать, выпадающие меню пропадает резко. Также не корректно работает пседоэлемент блока (.head__item_open). Не могу понять в чем проблема.

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll(".menu__js_open");

menu.forEach(menu => {
    menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menu.classList.toggle("active");
    })
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.head__list-nav {
  max-width: 419px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.head__link {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333333;
}

.head__item_open {
  position: relative;
}

.head__list-drop {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #1ed760;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 48px rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.4);
  border-radius: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: -25px;
  transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.head__item_open::after {
  content: "\02C6";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: -14px;
}

.menu__js_open.active .head__list-drop {
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-width: 205px;
  padding: 27px 0 24px 0;
}

.active.head__item_open::after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.head__item-drop {
  max-width: 159px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.head__item-drop_last,
.head__list-drop-languages .head__item-drop_last {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.head__link:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1749B3;
  color: #1749B3;
}

.head__link-drop:hover {
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  color: #1749B3;
}

.head__link-drop {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Bold", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #171717;
}
```

```html
<ul class="head__list-nav">
                                <li class="head__item_open menu__js_open"><a class="head__link" href="#">Subscriptions</a>
                                    <ul class="head__list-drop">
                                        <li class="head__item-drop"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">Netflix</a>
                                        <li class="head__item-drop"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">YouTube Premium</a>
                                        <li class="head__item-drop head__item-drop_last"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">Spotify</a>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="head__link" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                                <li><a class="head__link" href="#">Support</a></li>
                                <li><a class="head__link" href="#">About</a></li>
                            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в свойствах ширины и высоты

Было:

```
.head__list-drop {
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
}

.menu__js_open.active .head__list-drop {
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-width: 205px;
}
```

Стало:

```
.head__list-drop {
  width: 205px;
  max-height: 0;
}

.menu__js_open.active .head__list-drop {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll(".menu__js_open");

menu.forEach(menu => {
    menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menu.classList.toggle("active");
    })
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.head__list-nav {
  max-width: 419px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.head__link {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333333;
}

.head__item_open {
  position: relative;
}

.head__list-drop {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #1ed760;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 48px rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.4);
  border-radius: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: -25px;
  transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out;
  width: 205px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.head__item_open::after {
  content: "\02C6";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: -14px;
}

.menu__js_open.active .head__list-drop {
  max-height: 1000px;
  padding: 27px 0 24px 0;
}

.active.head__item_open::after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.head__item-drop {
  max-width: 159px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.head__item-drop_last,
.head__list-drop-languages .head__item-drop_last {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.head__link:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1749B3;
  color: #1749B3;
}

.head__link-drop:hover {
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  color: #1749B3;
}

.head__link-drop {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Bold", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #171717;
}
```

```html
<ul class="head__list-nav">
                                <li class="head__item_open menu__js_open"><a class="head__link" href="#">Subscriptions</a>
                                    <ul class="head__list-drop">
                                        <li class="head__item-drop"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">Netflix</a>
                                        <li class="head__item-drop"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">YouTube Premium</a>
                                        <li class="head__item-drop head__item-drop_last"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">Spotify</a>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="head__link" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                                <li><a class="head__link" href="#">Support</a></li>
                                <li><a class="head__link" href="#">About</a></li>
                            </ul>
```